# meta tag theme-color is not working in reactjs

Tags: css, colors, meta-tags

I want to change my chrome theme while visiting my site

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Lets explore the unseen world by using AR and VR products. This site is made for publishing AR and VR products " />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Should I know are you checking it on which browser.

Please find below reference for supported browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color